# what is -Denvironment option in maven?

Tags: java, maven

The current project in which I am working uses maven as build tool. For normal builds we use:

```
mvn clean install
```

But for creating EAR for some specific servers we use:

```
mvn clean install -Denvironment=SITE9003
```

Above command refers to a particular filter property file defined in project, and modify the build accordingly.

My question is what does -Denvironment exactly do and where is its configuration? By configuration I mean where is logic for the parameter passed as -Denvironment?

I tried looking at the manual pages of "clean" and "install" plugins, but I didn't find any reference of -Denvironment.

We are using Maven 2.2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Denvironment=test` triggers a maven build profile with the name `test`.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>environment</name>
        <value>test</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

[This](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) explains its exactly ;)

Comment: Ahaa, I was looking at wrong place. Thanks a lot :)